# relative paths in nested shell scripts - I can only edit the calling script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

say I have a shell script that reads a config file, which contains a relative path as a parameter - e.g. `filePath=./file.txt`

The shell script reads this in, and when it's run by itself `./script.sh`, it runs fine.

The issue comes, when I have a "menu" script, that can call `script.sh`. When I do so, using `. /absolute/path/to/script.sh`, the `.` in the config file suddenly becomes relative to `menu.sh`, not to `script.sh`. i.e. it now looks for `file.txt` in the wrong directory.

I can't edit `script.sh` to take an absolute path, and the config files must also stay as they are; so I need a way for `menu.sh` to call `script.sh` and have it act like it was called from a bash command line directly - so that `.` stays relative to `script.sh` and not relative to `menu.sh` while it's being run.

How would I best go about this?

Comment: Relative paths are resolved using the current working directory, not the location of the script being executed. Is `menu.sh` executing a `cd` command somewhere to change the working directory?

Comment: Related, your configuration file should be specifying absolute paths that don't depend on the state of the script using it, or at least provide an explicit base path to which the scripts can concatenate the relative path in order to get an absolute path.

Comment: @chepner yes, I know that's the ideal - but it's not how it's been done so I don't have a lot of choice on that one! As for your first point, would simply cd-ing to the same filepath as the script do the trick?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I don't know what would fix it. I'm pointing out, though, that `menu.sh` has a different notion of what the current working directory is when it attempts to use `$filePath` than `script.sh` does; that's where you need to address your efforts.

Comment: agreed; but `menu.sh` isn't using `$filepath`, `script.sh` is - but `script.sh` is acting like `$filepath` is relative to `menu.sh`

Comment: The answer to any of your questions is going to be "I don't know, because I can't see your code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
. /absolute/path/to/script.sh
```

what about doing this:

```
(cd /absolute/path/to;. script.sh)
```

It's not strictly equivalent since it creates a sub-shell, and all the variables created/modified in `script.sh` will be lost on exit, but otherwise does what you want.

to store the result of the command in a variable, just do:

```
result=$(cd /absolute/path/to;. script.sh)
```

EDIT: problem with the source/dot approach is that if the called script exits, it quits the current script. To avoid that (and if you're not looking for side effects, just replace by:

```
(cd /absolute/path/to;script.sh)
```

or

```
(cd /absolute/path/to;bash script.sh)
```

if `script.sh` doesn't have the proper bash shebang header.

Comment: so, are you suggesting that I set the variable that would have been set in the config file, in the menu script instead? Then it would be relative to the `menu` script, right? Which isn't what I want

Comment: edit (drastically :)) my answer. Sorry, I really read your question too fast.

Comment: would surrounding that answer with commandOutput=$() cause that to stop working? would I need two sets of brackets?

Comment: hmm ok, when I run it it works - but it's exiting `menu.sh` afterwards. Is there a way for it not to do that? The  inner `script` is calling either `end 0` or `abend "false" 74` (for example)

Comment: then you have to drop the `. ` prefix. Just do `result=$(cd /absolute/path/to;script.sh)`

Comment: when I do that I get "command not found" for `script.sh`, but it runs it ok with `. `

Comment: then do `result=$(cd /absolute/path/to;bash script.sh)`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!!! I would be very grateful if you could summarise that in your answer; and also maybe explain why each of the above cases work, so i can apply them myself in the future?